# Verify the format of a filename in Python

Tags: python

Every week I get two files with following pattern.

> EMEA_{sample}_Tracker_{year}_KW{week}

E.g.

> EMEA_G_Tracker_2019_KW52.xlsx
>
> EMEA_BC_Tracker_2019_KW52.xlsx

Next files would look like these

> EMEA_G_Tracker_2020_KW1.xlsx
>
> EMEA_BC_Tracker_2020_KW1.xlsx

Placeholders:

- sample = G or BC
- year = current year  [YYYY]
- week = calendar week [0 - ~52]

The only changes are made in the placeholders, everything else will stay the same.

How can I extract these values from the filename and check if the filename has this format?

Right now I only read all files using `os.walk()`:

```
path_files = "Files/"

files = []
for (_, _, filenames) in walk(path_files):
    files.extend(filenames)
    break
```

Comment: One suggestion would be to use **regex**.  Will post a proper answer for you soon.  Something simple like `^EMEA_[G|BC]_Tracker_20\d{2}_KW\d{2}.xlsx$` should do the trick.  What are you looking to do with the information once extracted?

Comment: All files are getting uploaded in a folder. I want to use the last G and BC file for fourther processing and every year I sort every file in an seperate folder. All 2019 files in folder 2019 and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `filename` is the name of the file you've got:

```
import re

result = re.match(r'EMEA_(.*?)_Tracker_(\d+)_KW(\d+)', filename)
sample, year, week = result.groups()
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this regex pattern (while functional) is **very loose** in terms of the values it will capture / allow to pass through the filter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to collect all files matching your pattern into a list using **regex** and [**list comprehension**](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-list-comprehensions-in-python-3).  Then you can use the list as you wish in later code.

```
import os
import re

# Compile the regular expression pattern.
re_emea = re.compile('^EMEA_(G|BC)_Tracker_20\d{2}_KW\d{1,2}.xlsx$')
# Set path to be searched.
path = '/home/username/Desktop/so/emea_files'

# Collect all filenames matching the pattern into a list.
files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if re_emea.match(f)]

# View the results.
print(files)
```

#### All files in the directory:

```
['EMEA_G_Tracker_2020_KW2.xlsx',
 'other_file_3.txt',
 'EMEA_G_Tracker_2020_KW1.xlsx',
 'other_file_2.txt',
 'other_file_5.txt',
 'other_file_4.txt',
 'EMEA_BC_Tracker_2019_KW52.xlsx',
 'other_file_1.txt',
 'EMEA_G_Tracker_2019_KW52.xlsx',
 'EMEA_BC_Tracker_2020_KW2.xlsx',
 'EMEA_BC_Tracker_2020_KW1.xlsx']
```

#### The results from pattern matching:

```
['EMEA_G_Tracker_2020_KW2.xlsx',
 'EMEA_G_Tracker_2020_KW1.xlsx',
 'EMEA_BC_Tracker_2019_KW52.xlsx',
 'EMEA_G_Tracker_2019_KW52.xlsx',
 'EMEA_BC_Tracker_2020_KW2.xlsx',
 'EMEA_BC_Tracker_2020_KW1.xlsx']
```

Hope this helps!  If not, just give me a shout.

Comment: The original poster did not ask for that; he wanted to **extract** three values (sample, year, week) from the filename (which, I believe, my answer does).

Comment: While you are correct OP mentions "extract" - the following statement "check if the filename has this format" suggests this is a check and the values on their own are not required.  Additionally, I asked what the user wishes to do with the files, which verifies this is a check.

Comment: My main question was how to extract these values ​​from the file name. I go through each file and put it in the correct folder (by year) and use the file with the highest KW, so the highlighted answer was the most appropriate for my question. On the other side @S3DEV your regex is more safe, but not future prove. If I get a file with the year 2120 I would have a problem.